# How to control tabIndex and focus trapping of elements w/o using positive values?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, tabindex

Maybe this is a bad idea entirely and am happy to take that as feedback; however, I'm looking for a good approach to controlling tabbable element on a document.

Requirements:

- Api for controlling the tabbing order that is out of flow with DOM order.
- Focus traps that COULD be cyclical and must be explicitly escaped.
- A method to put non-tabbable elements in tab flow.
- Written in Vanilla JS.
- [No positive tabIndex values](https://dequeuniversity.com/tips/tabindex-positive-numbers).

Note: This is a personal thought experiment not really sure if this is a good idea or not. Will take any kind of leads: articles, libraries, code snippets but obviously the best would be an answer that meets all the requirements (or any other ideas you can muster up)!

```css
    button {
      padding: 6px 8px;
      margin: 12px;
    }
    
    .focus-trap{
      padding: 24px;
      background: rgba(150, 150, 48, .5);
    }

    
    .now-tabbable {
      display: inline-flex;
      padding: 15px 8px;
      background: pink;
      margin: 12px;
      min-width: 45px;
      justify-content: center;
    }
```

```html
<!-- 
.focus-traps:

- Are meant to declare that tab focus are order by the programmer.
- Focus-traps can be cyclical. currently denoted by class but up for any ideas data-attr etc.

.now-tabbable:
- Are meant to declare that this element is part of the tab flow.

-->

<div class="focus-trap">
  <button>ZERO &times; escape</button>
  <button>two</button>
  <button>one</button>
  <button>three</button>
  <hr>

  <div class="focus-trap cyclical">
    <h1>Trap  focus in here until escape</h1>
    <button>four - B</button>
    <button>four - C</button>
    <button>four - A &times; escape</button>
  </div>
  <div class="now-tabbable">seven</div>
  <div class="now-tabbable">five</div>
  <div class="now-tabbable">six</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A focus trap isn't a good thing. It means a keyboard user is trapped inside a certain region and cannot move focus out of it any more. If you want to cycle through options inside a group, you can bind to arrow keys instead, and tab will still leave the group. Is that what you'd like?

Comment: "VanillaJS", which version? Which browser compatibility do you need?

Comment: Binding arrow keys is fine with me, this is the feedback I was looking for. We can use @next versions of vanillaJS. I'll use babel to compile it down.

Comment: it **is** ok to trap the focus in a group if that group is a modal dialog.  you don't want the focus going to the page in the background. i don't think that's what's going on in this case, but i just wanted to be clear that trapping the focus isn't always a bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you should avoid focus traps, except for modal contexts, like a modal dialogue.

The suggested solution here will instead establish a *focus group* with a [roving tab index](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#kbd_roving_tabindex) in which you can navigate focus by means of the arrow keys. TAB will then leave the group.

Keep in mind though, that you're using the focus group only for UI patterns where the behaviour can be expected. The ARIA standard mentions regarding [Keyboard Navigation Inside Components](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#kbd_general_within):

> […] strongly advised to use the same key bindings as similar components in common GUI operating systems as demonstrated in [§ 3. Design Patterns and Widgets](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#aria_ex).

You might for example also format your buttons visually in a way that they clearly make one group, similar to a [Toolbar](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#toolbar).

```js
class focusGroup { 
  
  constructor(el, cyclical: false) {
    this.cyclical = cyclical;
    
    // store children sorted by data-tabindex attribute
    this.children = Array.from(el.querySelectorAll('[data-tabindex]')).sort((el1, el2) => el1.getAttribute('data-tabindex') > el2.getAttribute('data-tabindex'));
    
    // remove tab index for all children
    this.children.forEach(childEl => childEl.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1'));
         
    // make first child tabbable
    this.children[0].setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
    this.i = 0;
    
    // bind arrow keys
    el.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
      if (e.key === 'ArrowRight' || e.key === 'ArrowDown') this.next();
      if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft' || e.key === 'ArrowUp') this.prev();
    });
  }
  
  next() {
    if (this.i < this.children.length -1) this.i += 1
    else if (this.cyclical) this.i = 0;
      
    this.updateFocus();
  }
  
  prev() {
    if (this.i > 0) this.i -= 1
    else if (this.cyclical) this.i = this.children.length -1;
    
    this.updateFocus();
  }
  
  updateFocus() {
    this.children.forEach(el => el.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1'));
    this.children[this.i].setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
    this.children[this.i].focus();
  }
} 

document.querySelectorAll('.focus-trap:not(.cyclical)').forEach(el => new focusGroup(el));

document.querySelectorAll('.focus-trap.cyclical').forEach(el => new focusGroup(el, true));
```

```css
button {
      padding: 6px 8px;
      margin: 12px 0;
    }
    
    .focus-trap{
      padding: 24px;
      background: rgba(150, 150, 48, .5);
    }

    
    .now-tabbable {
      display: inline-flex;
      padding: 15px 8px;
      background: pink;
      margin: 12px;
      min-width: 45px;
      justify-content: center;
    }
```

```html
<!-- 
.focus-traps:

- Are meant to declare that tab focus are order by the programmer.
- Focus-traps can be cyclical. currently denoted by class but up for any ideas data-attr etc.

.now-tabbable:
- Are meant to declare that this element is part of the tab flow.

-->

<div class="focus-trap">
  <button data-tabindex="0">ZERO &times; escape</button>
  <button data-tabindex="2">two</button>
  <button data-tabindex="1">one</button>
  <button data-tabindex="3">three</button>
</div>

<div class="focus-trap cyclical">
  <button data-tabindex>four - B</button>
  <button data-tabindex>four - C</button>
  <button data-tabindex>four - A &times; escape</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="now-tabbable">seven</button>
  <div class="now-tabbable">five</div>
  <div class="now-tabbable">six</div>
</div>
```

> Api for controlling the tabbing order that is out of flow with DOM order.

The visual order then will need to align with the focus order. In the example code, you can use `data-tabindex="i"` to control the

> Focus traps that COULD be cyclical and must be explicitly escaped.

You can call the class and provide the second argument as `true` to establish a *wrap over* or *cyclical* order.

> A method to put non-tabbable elements in tab flow.

Only elements with the attribute `data-tabindex` will be focussable.

> No positive tabIndex values.

You'll need to use positive `data-tabindexes`, but the example code will always only use `tabindex="0"` to make one single element focussable. Meaning if you re-enter the group by means of tab, the last focussed element will again be focussed.

Comment: as "normal" buttons, the user interaction would be a bit confusing.  a screen reader user, having landed on the "zero" button, would not know there are other buttons that can be navigated to with the arrow keys. they would just tab and focus would move to the "four" button and the user would be oblivious to the "two", "one", and "three" buttons.  however, if your buttons were wrapped in menu bar pattern (see https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#menu), then it would be ok.

Comment: Thanks slugolicious. Would you agree with the way the disclaimers in the answer?